# Why is it that this part of the vector has to be manipulated before we can let t=0

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm sure I missed some important part in calculus but I don't know where to look to find the answer.

A question that I'm doing is asking me to find the limit of a vector function. When I look up the answer to the problem, it leaves the $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ components alone but differentiates the $\mathbf{j}$ component, why is this? Why does the $\mathbf{k}$ component have to be manipulated when the others don't?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/myD36.png
$$ \lim_{t \to 0} \left( e^{-3t} \mathbf{i} + \frac{t^2}{\sin^2 t} \mathbf{j} + \cos 2t \mathbf{k}\right)$$

Edit:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD1sN.png
It didn't click with me that maybe the solution I was talking about would be helpful to post

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please typeset mathematics with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in the future.

Comment: Can you provide us what is written in the answer?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You have to clarify your question. You mention an *answer to the problem* but you're not including this in your question. Not good at all!

Comment: The reason is that at $0$, the $j$ term is of the form $0/0$ however both functions are well defined and differentiable around $0$. They used L'Hopital.

Comment: Maybe because the limit of $sinx/x$ is a special one?

Comment: Can you please show the whole solution you saw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that $\sin^2t=0$ when $t=0$ so it looks like you're dividing by $0$. To get around this one could apply l'Hopital's rule  to verify that $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t^2}{\sin^2 t} = 1$. The other coefficients are obviously continuous at $t=0$, so no calculation is needed.